# Setting up a controlled time lapse for Maps of different years

Tags: adobe-photoshop, maps, adobe-creative-suite, cartography

I have a number of maps of the same area from different years and would like to set up a file that allows me to transition between them, but I'd like to be able to control the transition manually in the final final, like having a slider bar with the different years on it. I have Adobe Creative Cloud to work with.

Comment: Was there a question? If you need interactivity, you'd need video.. http://video.stackexchange.com You can create some basic animations in Photoshop. If that's all you need... what have you tried? Where are you struggling?

Comment: Maybe you could use Adobe Animate?  However interactivity will likely involve using HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript, and unfortunately coding is generally off-topic here.

Comment: You need to provide more detail, and probably this is not the right exchange here. Are you saying you literally want to create "a file" with self-contained animation and slider? Or will all your customers/viewers also have Creative Cloud? Or is this just meant for yourself?